# reports in junit selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, report, webdriver

I use selenium web driver with junit in Eclipse. Advice me please how can I report test results?

I try make it in such way:

```
http://testerinyou.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-create-reports-using-junit.html?showComment=1342535781861#c6211334222001490686
```

But get errors during gereration:

```
Buildfile: E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml
build-subprojects:
init:
build-project:
[echo] WebDriver: E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml
[javac] E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml:43: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set,    defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
build:
Sector:
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\eclipse\WebDriver\junit
[junit] Running Sector
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Test Sector FAILED
junitreport:
[junitreport] Processing E:\eclipse\WebDriver\junit\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to E:\DOCUME~1\CONSUL~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\null255203125
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/E:/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs /optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] : Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference.
[junitreport] : Error! Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.
[junitreport] : Fatal Error! Could not compile stylesheet
[junitreport] Failed to process E:\eclipse\WebDriver\junit\TESTS-TestSuites.xml

BUILD FAILED
E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml:135: Errors while applying transformations: Fatal error during transformation

Total time: 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different possibilities to create reports for Selenium WebDriver.
A user developed a small library to create a html report with screenshots and so on.
For further information look here: https://github.com/vorburger/webdriver-reporting

Furthermore you could use another framework based on Selenium called Thucydides. It generates really nice looking html-reports and improves Selenium WebDriver. You can visit the official website for more information (www.thucydides.info)

You could use Ant oder TestNG to create a report for your tests.
Look here for more information: http://selftechy.com/2011/06/29/selenium-use-ant-to-generate-html-reports

Answer (score 0):

I like [UnitTH](http://junitth.sourceforge.net/) to generate test reports.

You can start it via ant or maven

Further questions?

Comment: Do you know where to find instructions for maven integration for UnitTH? I have googled for these, but they aren't easy to find.